# Can't get $TPU_NAME environment variable to work properly

Tags: tensorflow, kaggle, bert-language-model, google-cloud-tpu

I'm a newbie! I'm trying to train BERT model from scratch on a Kaggle kernel. Can't get the BERT `run_pretraining.py` script to work on TPUs. Works fine on CPUs though. I'm guessing the issue is with the $TPU_NAME environment variable.

```
!python run_pretraining.py \
--input_file='gs://xxxxxxxxxx/*' \
--output_dir=/kaggle/working/model/ \
--do_train=True \
--do_eval=True \
--bert_config_file=/kaggle/input/bert-bangla-test-config/config.json \
--train_batch_size=32 \
--max_seq_length=128 \
--max_predictions_per_seq=20 \
--num_train_steps=20 \
--num_warmup_steps=2 \
--learning_rate=2e-5 \
--use_tpu=True \
--tpu_name=$TPU_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

If the script is using a `tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/cluster_resolver/TPUClusterResolver), then you can simply instantiate the `TPUClusterResolver` without any arguments, and it'll automatically pickup the `TPU_NAME` (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/python/tpu/client/client.py#L47).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a rookie solution :P

run:

```
import os
os.environ
```

from the returned dictionary, you can get the address. Just copy paste it or something. It'll be in the form 'TPU_NAME': 'grpc://xxxxxxx'.